# How do I refer to ViewModel in my View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ok, it may be a silly question, but how do I reference my ViewModel object that I passed to the View in asp.net mvc?

so say my controller action has this at the end

```
return View(myModelObject);
```

in my view, how do I refer to it? Please use razor syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need 2 steps

1. use @model in the header of your view  (with small letter m)

   @model MyNamespace.MyModelObject
2. use the mode in your code inside a block or line statement as the following

Line

```
@Model
```

Block

```
@{
    Model
```

}

and remember you will use capital letter M

Answer (score 2):

You can reference it by the `Model` property of the `ViewDataDictionary` object.  Something like this to reference your ViewModel's property:

```
@{string StringVariable = Model.YourViewModelStringProperty;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@inherits` of `@model` [in the header of the view](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx).  Then, in the view's code, the object `Model` is a statically-typed reference to your model.